# Is there a way to install pytorch on python 3.12.0?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pytorch

I'm making an app using `gpt-neo` and I'm trying to install `torch`, but it won't install.

The error message is as follows:

```
C:\Users\Ben>pip install torch
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch
```

Is there any way to install `torch` without pip?

Comment: Can't you just use older Python such as 3.10?

Comment: I wanted to use the new Python 3.12 features on `pytorch`.

Comment: Then you have to wait for PyTorch devs, https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/110436

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I came to this thread doing research on vscode terminal.

I created virtual environment using py command

py -3.11 -m venv ai311

Link to my blog post if you want more details here

https://xeon2k.wordpress.com/2023/12/22/how-to-switch-between-python-versions-on-vs-code-terminal/

Comment: Is this for Python 3.12?

Comment: Works for 3.12. Pytorch does not support 3.12. Thus I wanted to switch to 3.11 in vs code terminal, and install pytorch.

Answer (score 11):

Its possible now if you use the nightly version.

Instructions here https://pytorch.org/, but pasted here for completeness

`pip3 install --pre torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/nightly/cu118`

Comment: Hi  Rick, It seemed to be going great until this: ERROR: Cannot install torchvision==0.17.0.dev20231202+cu118, torchvision==0.17.0.dev20231203+cu118, torchvision==0.18.0.dev20231220+cu118 and torchvision==0.18.0.dev20231221+cu118 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

The conflict is caused by:
    torchvision 0.18.0.dev20231221+cu118 depends on numpy ----> using Python 3.12 on W11

Comment: only worked for me if i truncated the url: pip3 install --pre torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/nightly

Answer (score 4):

I also tried to find out how to install PyTorch without using pip like you
but the answer is: **impossible.**

You can find wheel files for all environments at https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch/ but they haven't uploaded them yet.

The nightly build will probably come out first even if they do upload them.

Unfortunately, as of now, PyTorch only supports Python up to 3.11.x. Therefore, you may find it helpful to install the latest version of 3.11 [(3.11.6)](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3116/).

Comment: Where do I get nightly builds by the way?

Answer (score -3):

You need to downgrade your current Python version from 3.12.0 to 3.11.5.